# Path of War: What exaclty do you get from the feat Martial Training?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The [Martial Training 1](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/feats/martial-training-i-combat/) (from Path of War) feat reads as follows

> Prerequisite(s): Base attack bonus +3 or Knowledge (martial) 3 ranks.
>
> Benefit(s): Select a martial discipline. The associated skill for this discipline is now a class skill. Your initiation modifier is chosen from Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma. Your martial initiator level maneuvers granted by this feat (and subsequent Martial Training feats) is equal to half your character level + your initiation modifier. You may select any two maneuvers from the 1st level maneuvers from this discipline, and you may ready one of your maneuvers for use. You may recover one maneuver by expending a full round action to recover it.

I'm looking at the part about "Your martial initiator level maneuvers granted by this feat (and subsequent Martial Training feats) is equal to half your character level + your initiation modifier. You may select any two maneuvers from the 1st level maneuvers from this discipline" It's saying that the level of abilities granted is my initiator level; so for example, say I'm 5th level. This would give me access to 2nd level maneuvers, but then it goes on to say I still only get 1st levels?

This feat also leads into a wealth of content on the martial disciplines which seem to have their own way of gaining abilities.

So my question is: can someone clarify on when a non-martial class uses these feats, how they gain abilities and what level abilities they gain?

Comment: I should really read Path of War sometime... I feel like I could answer this question but I'm lacking some important details. In lieu of something more useful, I edited your question to use appropriate quotation/grammar and clarify the question. If you feel I've strayed too far from your intent, feel free to roll it back or reedit it.

Comment: i mean thats fine thanks, but how would you interpret just that feat description? it seems to contradict itself.

Comment: Like I said, I don't have an answer. See if @Cyrad's or another poster successfully explains it. I would *guess* that it gives you level 1 maneuvers as a level 2+(ability score) level character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initiator level does NOT determine what maneuvers you learn. Rather, they determine the maximum maneuver level for the purpose of multiclassing. **The maneuver system has a cap on the number of maneuvers you know and can ready.** The quantity and level of maneuvers you can learn and ready is entirely determined by whatever classes or feats you gain. If a feat says "you learn two 1st level maneuvers and can ready one of them," it means *exactly* that.

I will explain the feat in more detail.

1. You select one martial discipline and gain its associated skill as a class skill.
2. You gain an initiator level equal to 1/2 your character level + your initiation modifier (which you choose from your Int, Wis, or Cha modifier). This level cannot exceed your character level, as per Initiator Level errata on page 26. This initiator level applies to all maneuvers you gained through the Martial Training feats.
3. You learn two 1st level maneuvers from your discipline. The maneuver system does not allow you to learn additional maneuvers unless you take more Martial Training feats or gain a level in a martial disciple class (a class that has the "maneuvers readied" class feature).
4. You can ready only one maneuver you know.
5. You can spend a full-round action to recover a used maneuever.